# Text alignment on UITextView after pinch recognizer

Tags: ios, uitextview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

My problem is: after use UIPinchGestureRecognizer, the UiTextView loses the text alignment. It is showed in next pictures.

[image: UITextView before resize]

UITextView before resize

[image: UITextView after resize - Here is written: "StackOverFlow"]

UITextView after resize - Here is written: "StackOverFlow"

And my code is:

```
- (void) handlePinchSubView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:textView.font.fontName size:textView.font.pointSize/recognizer.scale];
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the font of the textview, but you aren't changing the position of the view, causing it to go offscreen.

When the pinch happens, add something along the lines of:

```
textView.frame = recognizer.view.frame
```

Comment: The problem is in textView.contentInset. I have to adjust it.